# Clustering pictures by time and location

Tags: cluster-analysis, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to cluster pictures according to the location they were taken and the time they were taken. My clustering algorithm requires me to define a distance function between every two points, (in this case, every two pictures.)

Any idea for good transformation for the time parameter? I have thought about using Euclidean distance for the Lat/Long, but I have no idea which transformation is needed for the time parameter in order to compute distance affected by time.

Answer (score 3):

Try using e.g. DBSCAN. If you look at the generalized version (GDBSCAN), it is fairly obvious that you can also define **two threshold parameters**, a spatial threshold (say, 100 meters) and a temporal threshold (e.g. 1 day) at the same time.

That is a straightforward extension of DBSCAN within the Generalized DBSCAN framework.

To accelerate your algorithm with an index will be a bit trickier, but ELKI should be flexible enough to allow such extensions and be really fast.

As for Lat/Long, **don't use Euclidean distance on latitude-longitude**. It's okay if you first project your data into a local coordinate system such as a single UTM zone (this doesn't work if your data spans the whole globe). But use one of the great circle approximations. ELKI already has indexing support for this, you should be able to add the time component easily (in particular, as you only need thresholds).

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, you suggest an heuristic approach: try to set 1 day s 100 meter. I am trying to find something more systematically.

Comment: Well, if you know of any mathematical relationship of meters to days... I don't. You know, sometimes you *have* to set some parameters to define your problem more precisely and get better results. Parameter-free algorithms usually are crap.